# Meteor Bootstrap 3 Form does not Submit

Tags: meteor

I'm working with meteor@1.1.10 and twbs:bootstrap@3.3.5

I can get a modal window to spawn, close, and register a button has been clicked.  I cannot get it to read any information from a form though.  It just closes.  I included a console message and it never shows up to either the browser or the command prompt.

Is there a way to do this without including another package?   I've included my modal HTML template and Javascript.  I'm hoping it's just something missed in the code.

Below is the HTML:

```
<template name="emodal">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Spends Email Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="emailspends">
            <label for="input">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" name="emailto" required>
            <label for="input">Character Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="charname" required>
            <input type="submit" id="sendemail" class="email" value="Email Spends" data-dismiss="modal">
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Below is the Javascript:

```
Template.emodal.events({
    "submit .emailspends": function (event) {
      console.log(Meteor.user().emails[0].address);
      // Prevent default browser form submit
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get value from form element
      //var emailto = event.target.emailto.value;

      var emailto = event.target.emailto.value;
      var charname = event.target.charname.value;

      var title = "Experience spends for " + charname;

      Meteor.call('sendEmail', emailto,
      'zbottorff@uwalumni.com', title,
      'Yup, modal testies.');

      // Clear form
      event.target.emailto.value = "";
      event.target.charname.value = "";
    }
  });
```

Update: Realized I should include this, but I did make sure I could get a submit-able template without it being in a modal window.  Now I want to turn it into a modal and it's not submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah!  I found it just after I posted this.

I had too many parts to my submit button.  I removed the "Class" and "id" parts, changed my Javascript to look for a 'submit form' event instead.  Voala!  Got the bugger to work.